# Response after multiples form submit

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, scriptlet

I'm trying to implement a synchronize token and It worked but the last request (or the others after the first) I would like to ignore.
For example:
If I don't put a request.getResquestDispatcher() or response.sendRedirect, these others requests will go to a blank page (nullPointer, because there's no command).
Also, the first request, which did everything ok, won't send to the user the messages that everything worked fine.

Here's how I'm doind.

```
@Override
  public void executa(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
HttpSession session = request.getSession();

Object attribute = session.getAttribute("formToken");
System.out.println(attribute);

if (!request.getParameter("tokenHidden").equals(attribute.toString()))
{       
    return;
}
session.setAttribute("formToken", 1);
}
//some stuff...
response.sendRedirect("coletarproduto.jsp?mensagem=Produto Atualizado");
```

I'm doind the synchronizer token this way:

```
<form action="wms" method="post">   
<% session.setAttribute("formToken",Math.random()); %>
<input type="hidden" value="${formToken}" name="tokenHidden" /> 
</form>
```

I didn't like to use scriptlet, but I can't think other solution either.

I'm using Tomcat and jsp. 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you really sending the result message as a query string parameter?

Comment: i KNOW the following answer isnt what you asked for, but when i want to avoid multiple requests from a user (what i call triple-click ;) ) i usually show a 'Please wait...' div that blocks all further user input on the onSubmit event. Its really easy to implement, but as I said, only works for "real users", not for DOS attacks for example

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes. I am. Shouldn't I? why? How could that be done?

Comment: @jambriz, but this way would be using javascript, right? I would like to do in serverside.
Thanks.

Comment: @viictoorh a malign user of naive web applications (as me) can intercept the response and change the query string message value to *You have been hacked. Your credit card number is mine now* and scare the users. Of course, this is just to illustrate a problem in your app.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza. I See... Actually, It's going to be an app to use inside the company, for a "mobile browser", etc... It's not a problem that would make us worry. But, if you have an idea how could I avoid this...

Comment: @viictoorh - I am not sure. But you can use custom headers with request. Like "client-id". Then on server side, create on table storing "client-id" & `last request time`. If difference between current request time & `last request time from DB` for current client-id is less than some value, then treat it as multiple click. Client Id can be user id. Also you may want to check `User-Agent` to check from which device request is sent.